# Not able to run C call from go

Tags: go, cgo, gccgo

I am trying to run a C call from go language code. Here is the program I am running:

```
package main

// #include<proxy.h>

import "C"
import "fmt"

func main(){
    fmt.Println(C.CMD_SET_ROUTE)
}
```

Here is the content of the file proxy.h:

```
#ifndef PROXY_H
#define PROXY_H

#include <netinet/in.h>

#ifdef CMD_DEFINE
#   define cmdexport
#else
#   define cmdexport static
#endif

cmdexport const int CMD_SET_ROUTE = 1;
cmdexport const int CMD_DEL_ROUTE = 2;
cmdexport const int CMD_STOP      = 3;
```

Now, here is the error I am getting when trying to run that program:

```
pensu@ubuntu:~$ go run test.go 
# command-line-arguments
could not determine kind of name for C.CMD_SET_ROUTE
```

I am using gccgo-5 and go version 1.4.2. Could you please help me figure out what exactly is the issue here? TIA.

Comment: I would avoid trying to use gccgo *and* go1.4.2. Stick with the default toolchain until you have a specific need for gccgo, to avoid added confusion.

Comment: There are lot of syntactic errors in your code. It would be better if you go through [this](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo) blog post before using cgo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Four things:

- You should be using double quotes when including `proxy.h`, as it resides in the same directory as your `.go` file.
- There cannot be a blank line before you "C" comment and the "C" import.
- You are missing an `#endif` at the end `proxy.h`.
- You need to define `CMD_DEFINE` before including `proxy.h`. Otherwise, Go cannot access the static variable.

Below is the corrected code:

```
package main

// #define CMD_DEFINE
// #include "proxy.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main(){
    fmt.Println(C.CMD_SET_ROUTE)
}
```

```
#ifndef PROXY_H
#define PROXY_H

#include <netinet/in.h>

#ifdef CMD_DEFINE
#   define cmdexport
#else
#   define cmdexport static
#endif

cmdexport const int CMD_SET_ROUTE = 1;
cmdexport const int CMD_DEL_ROUTE = 2;
cmdexport const int CMD_STOP      = 3;

#endif
```